# ContextMenu on Webview is not displaying correctly in JavaFX

Tags: css, webview, javafx, javafx-webengine

I have a webview where I have given context menu options based on the type of HTML elements. Few elements have 3 menu items and few other elements have 6 menu items.
[image]

[image]

Above two images are some examples. On right clicking a text field, I'm getting 6 menu options. On right clicking a link, I'm getting two menu items.

Now, I have an issue when I right click on text field again. It shows the context menu with the size of previous menu (i.e. with only two rows). However, if I right click again on text field it displays correctly. Below is the image showing that.

[image]

Is this an issue in JavaFX or am I missing something? Please help.
My code is like this.

```
List<MenuItem> menus = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
if(action.equals("Editbox")){
                createContextMenu(webView, VerifyActionsUtil.getActionItems(action), x, y);
            }else if(action.equals("Link")){
                createContextMenu(webView, VerifyActionsUtil.getActionItems(action), x, y);
            }else{
                createContextMenu(webView, menus, x, y);
}

public void createContextMenu(WebView webView, List<MenuItem> menus, int x, int y) {
        menu.getItems().clear();
        if(menus!=null && menus.size()>0){
            menu.getItems().addAll(menus);
            menu.show(webView, x, y);
        }
    }
```

`action` is an object used to check the type of element. `VerifyActionsUtil.getActionItems(action)` gives the list of menu items depending on the `action`.

```
public class VerifyActionsUtil {


    MenuItem item0=new MenuItem("check_if_enabled-True");
    MenuItem item1=new MenuItem("check_if_exists-True");
    MenuItem item2=new MenuItem("check_if_displayed-True");
    MenuItem item3=new MenuItem("get_the_text_of_the_textfield");

    public VerifyActionsUtil() {

        item0.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                insert(item0);
            }
        });
        //similar actions for other menu items
        //insert method inserts the details into a table.

   }
   public List<MenuItem> getActionItems(String objectType) {

        List<MenuItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
        if("Editbox".equals(objectType)){
            menuItems.add(item0);
            menuItems.add(item9);
            menuItems.add(item1);
            menuItems.add(item10);
            menuItems.add(item2);
            menuItems.add(item3);
            menuItems.add(item4);
            menuItems.add(item5);
        }else if("Radio".equals(objectType)){
            menuItems.add(item1);
            menuItems.add(item10);
            menuItems.add(item2);
            menuItems.add(item0);
            menuItems.add(item9);
            menuItems.add(item5);
        }
        return menuItems;
    }
```

Comment: I can not reproduce this behavior.. can you post an MCVE showing the issue?

Comment: or Full IDE project so we can invent a workaround more properly.